# Google & Facebook login on the same page - how to distinct

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, google-signin

I have implemented google login and facebook login.
In the `PageLoad()` method I get `code` parameter from query string to get token and authenticate users.
But query string parameter is same for both "`code`":

```
if (this.Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
```

Is it possible to somehow distinct if request came from FB or Google?
Or maybe the best practice is to set different redirect url for both, now both redirect back to home page.

Comment: You could do that, when you build your redirect url add another query string parameter putting the provideNname, then check that when you get hit your PageLoad?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed required to use different redirect URL's for both. That way it becomes trivial to distinguish between them.

The other option is use a hub, such as [The Identity Hub](https://www.theidentityhub.com). That way you can add account providers without impacting your application.